# Error while trying Python Requests with client side Certificate

Tags: python, python-requests, x509certificate

I would like to use python requests with client certificate to make a requests to a website like google.com.
This is my example :
When I use this :  `requests.get('https://google.com', verify=False)`, I get a warning. I have download the certificate from google.com with openssl with this command:

```
echo | openssl s_client -servername google.com -connect google.com:443 |  sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > gogl.crt
```

I would like to make requests with python3 requests module:

```
requests.get('https://google.com', verify='/path/to/gogl.crt')
```

When I do this I get an error:

.....
.....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: I think `verify` must be a boolean

Comment: just do requests.get('https://google.com')  remove the verify part and test

Comment: @NarcisseDoudieuSiewe this does not work

Comment: @dmx what is the error?

Comment: @NarcisseDoudieuSiewe seems to be certificate issue

Comment: @dmx 1) do a "pip install certifi" thus, add "import certifi, pathlib" and "requests.get('https://google.com', verify=str(pathlib.Path(certifi.where())))"  what do you get?

Comment: @NarcisseDoudieuSiewe got 200

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249505/discussion-between-dmx-and-narcisse-doudieu-siewe).